# select only first child in css when hovering

Tags: html, css

so here is my code:

```
ul.primary li:hover > a{
    transform:translate(7px,7px);
    -ms-transform:translate(7px,7px);
    -webkit-transform:translate(7px,7px);
}
```

I want to select only the first "a" tag. Its for a menu and i dont want the links in the next "ul li a" to be translated 7 px down and right. For some reason when i try to change the css of the sub menu to:

```
ul.sub li a:hover {
    -moz-transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -o-transition: color 0 ease-in;
    transition: none;
}
```

the transition is still there.

here is the html of the menu:

```
<div class="wrap">
<span class="decor"></span>
<nav>
  <ul class="primary">
    <li>
      <a href="">WORKS</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="">CERAMICS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">EXHIBITIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">OTHERWORKS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">PHOTOS</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">OTHER PROJECTS</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="">INSTAGRAM FEED</a></li>
        <li><a href="">PUBLICATIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">WARDOBE DESIGN</a></li>
      </ul>  
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: try using `:first-child`.

Comment: show the html [art of your code please  ul.primary li:hover > a:first-child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved mmy problem:

```
ul.primary > li:hover > a
```

was the correct selector.

Comment: For reference, first-child refers to the first direct descendent/child of a parent within the DOM, you seem to be referring to direct descendants/children which (although including the first-child) is not the same thing. Ensuring clarity in terminology will help the community give better, more relevent, answers in the future.

Comment: In my mind your answer should select _ALL_ links under `li` which are child of `ul.primary`. Correct me if I am wrong. This is not first child selector, it applies to all links.

Answer (score 0):

You need `ul.primary li:first-child:hover > a` and

```
ul.sub li:hover a {
    -moz-transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -o-transition: color 0 ease-in;
    transition: none;
}
```

Comment: I tried this also, and it does not work. this just selects the first "a" tag in the top tier of the menu, and nothing else works as it should.

Comment: Maybe your html structure is different then I thought. Try `ul.primary li:hover > a:first-child`